# How to push a div from the top in percentage with css?

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, fluid-layout

I'm trying to make a `div` inside another `div` to be placed 70% from the top of the parent `div` so no matter what the screen size is the inner `div` should flow up or down to adjust for it (kind of like fluid layouts but vertically). I tried doing the following:

http://jsfiddle.net/uxaVe/

But the `padding-top` is fixed even though I have it set in percentage, I must be doing something wrong but I'm not sure what it is, could you guys help me out? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the padding, and replace with

```
position:absolute;
top:70%;
```